# CSV not importing

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am trying to create a csv editor. I want to import a csv and convert it to tables in html. This is the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <h1>Build Table</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <div>
        <table id="blacklistgrid">

            <tr class="Row">
                <td>
                    <input type="text"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add Row!</button>
        <button><a href="#" class="export">Export Table data into Excel</a></button>
    </div>

    <script>

function parseResult(result) {
    var resultArray = [];
    result.split("\n").forEach(function(row) {
        var rowArray = [];
        row.split(",").forEach(function(cell) {
            rowArray.push(cell);
        });
        resultArray.push(rowArray);
    });
    return resultArray;
}

function createTable(array) {
    var content = "";
    array.forEach(function(row) {
        content += "<tr>";
        row.forEach(function(cell) {
            content += "<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"" + cell + "\"/></td>" ;
        });
        content += "</tr>";
    });
    document.getElementById("#blacklistgrid").innerHTML = content;
}

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery('#btnAdd').click(function () {
          jQuery( ".Row" ).clone().appendTo( "#blacklistgrid" );

        });

        var file = document.getElementById('file');
file.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var f = file.files[0];
     reader.onload = function(e) {
        var CSVARRAY = parseResult(e.target.result); //this is where the csv array will be
        createTable(CSVARRAY);
    };
    reader.readAsText(f);
});

     });


$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
      csv = '"' + $rows.map(function(i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
          $cols = $row.find('input');

        return $cols.map(function(j, col) {
          var $col = $(col),
            text = $col.val();

          return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

      }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
      .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
      .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';

    // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
    if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

      var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
      });

      // Crashes in IE 10, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge
      // See MS Edge Issue #10396033
      // Hence, the deliberate 'false'
      // This is here just for completeness
      // Remove the 'false' at your own risk
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

    } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {
      // HTML5 Blob
      var blob = new Blob([csv], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'
      });
      var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvUrl
        });
    } else {
      // Data URI
      var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvData,
          'target': '_blank'
        });
    }
  }

  // This must be a hyperlink
  $(".export").on('click', function(event) {
    // CSV
    var args = [$('#blacklistgrid'), 'export.csv'];

    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);

    // If CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
  });
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get the import function to work. And, these are the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at createTable ((index):54)
    at FileReader.reader.onload ((index):69)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, `row.split(",").forEach(...)` can just be `rowArray = row.split(",");`

Comment: You never call `createTable(CSVARRAY);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `#` in the argument to `document.getElementById`. It should be:

```
document.getElementById("blacklistgrid").innerHTML = content;
```

or using jQuery:

```
$("#blacklistgrid").html(content);
```

Comment: thanks it worked. However, the add row does not work after loading the csv?

Comment: `createTable()` doesn't give `class="Row"` to the rows it creates.

Comment: You should also use `.first()` or `.last()` in the function adding a row, otherwise it will clone the entire table.